# Using Azure Scale out on Orchard CMS 1.10 with multiple tenants

Tags: azure, orchardcms

I creating a site using Orchard CMS and will be hosting it on an Azure Web App. I have just upgraded to 1.10 and want to know how Scale Out is handled with regards to the App_Data folder (I will be using multi-tenants).

I have installed the Microsoft Azure Services to allow Azure Blob storage for the media folder which is working great, but how do I now configure Orchard so that the App_Data is also stored on Blob storage?

Or is the App_Data folder meant to be shared between instances?  If so, is it synchronized immediately?

I have tried creating a tenant with two (web app) instances and couldn't navigate to it via the second instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Azure App Services the file system is shared across instances. However if you create a tenant dynamically, you will need to restart the other instance to take it into account. An alternative is to use the Message Bus feature which will tell the other instance to restart by itself when a tenant is created, or any other configuration is changed. This Message Bus can use SQL Server Azure or Azure Cache as the message brokers.

Comment: Thanks Seb.  I restarted the entire web app and the tenant is now available on both nodes.  Is this a standard Azure Web app feature?  The message bus seems a bit of overkill for my needs, so can I script it using Kudu or similar?

Comment: It's overkill if you create tenants only once in a while. If not then it's not overkill at all, and super easy to setup. Once hybrid approach could be to use a FileSystemWatcher implementation for the message bus when on Azure App Services as it's using a shared FS. I will file an issue for that.